# How to unit test local variables with jasmine?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I'm trying to test two local variables, `language` and `translationObj`, in the code below:

```
public loadDictionary () {

    this.source$ = this.httpService
            .get(...)
            .map((response) => {
                const language = this.lang // this.lang contains a value like  'en_GB';
                const translationObj = this.convertStringsToArrays(response.data.translations) // contains an object like {'name' : 'Donald', 'age': '16'};

                // other stuff going on here
            });

        return this.source$;
    }
}
```

`language` returns a string like 'en_GB', and the `translationObj` returns an object of key/values like `{'name' : 'Donald', 'age': '16'}`

The two issues I am having...

1. How to mock the data for the two variables in my test?
2. Should I be testing the variable (`language`) or the value being assigned to it (`this.lang`)?

Comment: You can't access them as they're inside a closure. You'd need to expose them to monitor them.

Comment: Private things like this aren't part of the public API of the unit you're testing.  Your unit tests shouldn't care what's going on internally, just that the unit as a whole behaves as it should.  Presumably it uses those variables in some way and returns other visible results - _that's_ what you should be inspecting in your unit tests.

Comment: Thank you both. @James - yes thats right, those variables do other stuff. The test I have written for loadDictionary () actually does pass, but a code coverage tool was telling me that this.lang and this.convertStringsToArrays where not covered in the test. So I guess these functions require their own test